# How can I return the number of active VS Code workspaces in terminal

Tags: shell, unix, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, zsh

I am trying to customize my zsh terminal and have added a custom segment that displays the number of currently active Visual Studio workspaces as shown in the photo below.

[ZSH Prompt Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulgzs.png)

The current method I am using is this:

```
vscode() {

  local nums='0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9'
  local subs='₀-₁-₂-₃-₄-₅-₆-₇-₈-₉'

  echo "%F{030} \ue37d $(code-insiders --status | grep -c '|  Window (~/' | tr $nums $subs)"

}
```

**The problem is that this is slow and causes my prompt to render very slowly.**

Is there a better method I could use to fix this issue?